# how do create while loop input for accept only 1 or 2 as input in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

```
x = 0
while not in range(1,3):
    x = input("Choose1 or 2 : ")
```

I tried many times this code to accept only 1 or 2 values. But I failed to stop the loop after entering proper input. Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your code:

- You're not checking the value of `x` in the `while` loop.
- The result of an `input` statement is a string, so you can't compare it with an int without explicitly converting it to int format.

```
x = 0
while x not in range(1,3):
    x = int(input("Choose1 or 2 : "))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking a variable in `while not in range(1, 3):` because you did not define any variable in that statement,

So you should enter a valid statement, like this

```
while x not in range(1, 3):
```

OR

```
while not x in range(1, 3):
```

Second, `input('...')` will always return `str` type, not `int`, so you should change it to

```
x = input('Choose 1 or 2: ')
```

So your full code will be:

```
x = 0
while x not in range(1,3):
    x = int(input("Choose1 or 2 : "))
```

You can add an exception if the `x` is not 1 or 2, like this:

```
x = int() #same as x = 0
while x not in range(1, 3):
    try:
       x = int(input('Choose 1 or 2: '))
    except:
       print('Chosen number is not 1 or 2')
    if x not in range(1, 3):
       print('Chosen number is not 1 or 2')
```